# how to add new fonts to pyfpdf

Tags: python, fonts, web2py, fpdf, truetype

i've tried to copy a dejavucondensed.ttf into pyfpdf/font/
But no luck when i tried

```
>>> from pyfpdf import *
>>> p = FPDF()
>>> p.add_font('dejavucondensed')
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfd' in file pyfpdf/font/dejavucondensed.font 
on line 2, 
but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a Unicode/encoding problem (see the  [PEP linked in the message](http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html)). I do not have pypdf installed here, but according to the [reference documentation for add_font](http://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/wiki/AddFont) you need to use the `uni` parameter:

```
pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', uni=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's looking at this all this time later, try this. I'm in Ubuntu Linux using Python 3.8. Go to your installation of `fpdf`, which for me was in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fpdf`.

If there is *not* a folder named **fonts** there, do a `mkdir fonts`. Grab the `ttf` file for your font from any number of sources and place it in the **fonts** folder. I wanted Calibri Regular and named my file `calibri_regular.ttf`.

Then in your interpreter or script:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()

pdf.add_font('Calibri Regular', '', 'calibri_regular.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font('Calibri Regular', '', 12)
```

At this point you're ready to write to the PDF in that font.

Comment: Are you sure the folder should be named **fonts** and not **font**

Comment: I no longer have access to the machine I did this on, but to the best of my recollection yes, ````fonts```` is the correct nomenclature.