# Can't print specific character using FPDF in python

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to print this word in Arabic

```
الله
```

I tried many fonts but still, the FPDF is printing it as box (tofu box, is what it is called I guess)

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import arabic_reshaper

pdf = FPDF('P', 'mm', "A4")
pdf.add_page()
pdf.add_font('dejavu', "", "DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf", uni=True)
pdf.set_font('dejavu', '', 10)
pdf.multi_cell(69, 5, arabic_reshaper.reshape("الله"), "", ln=1)
pdf.output("mypdf.pdf")
```

If I dont use arabic reshaper the result is [image] which is not the correct word as entered.

Result is this box[image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028375/how-to-add-new-fonts-to-pyfpdf#:~:text=Go%20to%20your%20installation%20of,it%20in%20the%20fonts%20folder.

Comment: I was able to run your code without issues grabbing a copy of that font somewhere online, except that I had to pass `uni=True` to `add_font()` to ensure it loaded with the correct encoding. I could not reproduce your issue - with that option set, the text shows in the PDF.

Comment: You used the same font ? DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf ??

Comment: Hi, did you get the result as ```ه ل ل ا``` ?? if yes then thats not correct. I have updated the code with additional info

Comment: @Grismar any idea over this issue?

Comment: Ah, yes, it did look like that - sorry I don't speak or read the language, so I was unable to tell if that was undesirable or just a stylistic difference. With the reshaper, I do also get the tofu block. Have you checked if the font you picked can actually correctly render the text in something like a word processor? (i.e. MS Word, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the solution is something like this:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from arabic_reshaper import reshape
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from warnings import filterwarnings

pdf = FPDF()

pdf.add_page()
pdf.add_font("NotoSansArabic", style="", fname="NotoSansArabic-Regular.ttf", uni=True)
pdf.set_font('NotoSansArabic', '', 10)
original_text = 'الله'

reshaped_text = reshape(original_text)
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)

pdf.write(8, original_text)
pdf.ln(8)

pdf.write(8, reshaped_text)
pdf.ln(8)

pdf.write(8, bidi_text)
pdf.ln(8)

filterwarnings('ignore')
pdf.output('mypdf.pdf')
filterwarnings('default')
```

I could not get it to work with the font you provided, but the Google font used here can be downloaded for free. It appears some part of `'الله'` is causing the issue, because something like `'مرحبا'` does work in Deja Vu Sans Condensed.

The `filterwarnings("ignore")` is there because the `pdf.output` generates warnings which seem not to affect the result, but you may wish to look into them instead of just ignoring them:

```
[..]\site-packages\fpdf\ttfonts.py:670: UserWarning: cmap value too big/small: -65241
  warnings.warn("cmap value too big/small: %s" % cm)
```

However, the script now appears to do what you want, also showing the initial look and the reshaped look before fixing the direction.

Your question is different, but I found the solution here: [Problem writing a mix of English and Arabic text in PDF using Python pyFPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69098666/problem-writing-a-mix-of-english-and-arabic-text-in-pdf-using-python-pyfpdf). The warning occurred with Deja Vu as well, so it's not caused by the specific font.