# How to create a PDF file from a non-English (Persian) text using fpdf in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, farsi

I want to write a Farsi text and create its 'PDF' file. I installed and used the fpdf module, but I got an error.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
def export_pdf():
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=15)
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt='این متن فارسی است.', ln=1, align='R')
    pdf.output('output.pdf')
```

Error is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 51-53: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Do you have any solution?

My code:

Comment: does this help? https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/set_doc_option/index.html#core_fonts_encoding

Comment: You may want to look at PyMuPDF: it supports right-to-left scripts.

Comment: My response is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71551293/15144104).

Answer (score 1):

Add `#! coding: utf-8` to the beginning of the file.